# What am I doing wrong with this query?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, database

I can't seem to find why this function doesn't insert records into the database. :( 
I get no error messages or whatsoever, just nothing in the database.

**EDIT: this is how my query looks now .. still nothing ..**

```
connection.Open();
XmlNodeList nodeItem = rssDoc.SelectNodes("/edno23/posts/post");

foreach (XmlNode xn in nodeItem)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    msgText = xn["message"].InnerText;
    C = xn["user_from"].InnerText;
    avatar = xn["user_from_avatar"].InnerText;
    string   endhash =  GetMd5Sum(msgText.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@endhash",endhash);
    cmd.CommandText  = "Select * FROM posts Where hash=@endhash";
    SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string msgs = reader["hash"].ToString();

        if (msgs != endhash || msgs == null)
        {
            sql = "INSERT INTO posts([user],msg,avatar,[date],hash) VALUES(@username,@messige,@userpic,@thedate,@hash)";
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", C);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@messige", msgText.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userpic", avatar.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@thedate", dt);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@hash", endhash);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// executes query
            adapter.Update(data);// saves the changes
        }
    }

    reader.Close();
}

connection.Close();
```

Comment: Have you verified that you enter the while loop, and also come into the if block?

Comment: use the debugger to step through the code, you'll learn more faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does nodeItem actually have any items in it? If not, the contents of the foreach loop aren't being executed.

What's the adapter and data being used for? The queries and updates seem be done via other commands and readers.

What does 'hash' actually contain? If it's a hash, why are you hashing the content of the hash  inside the while loop? If not, why is it being compared against a hash in the query `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE hash = @endhash`?

Won't closing the connection before the end of the while loop invalidate the reader used to control the loop?

Comment: I'm doing the hash thing cuz i want to compare if the content is 100% unique if its not insert the content if its identical to previous content skip to next :) i already moved the connection closing

Comment: @Aviatrix: I think you missed the point with the hash question. The `hash` column contains a hash, yes? You specifically query for records that have the hash contained in `endhash`. You then *hash* the value contained in that column, which is 99.99% *gauranteed* to produce a completely different hash, and compare it with the original query value - *never* going to match.

Comment: i fixd that .. i wanted to compare the two hashes but by mistake i hashed the hash .. o.O any who .. im still not getting any records added :(

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things going on here...

You are using the command 'cmd' to loop over records with a datareader, and then using the same 'cmd' command inside the while statement to execute an insert statement.  You declared another command 'cmdAdd' before but don't seem to use it anywhere; is that what you intended to use for the insert statement?

You also close your data connection inside the while loop that iterates over your datareader.  You are only going to read one record and then close the connection to your database that way; if your conditional for inserting is not met, you're not going to write anything to the database.

EDIT:

You really should open and close the connection to the database outside the foreach on the xmlnodes.  If you have 10 nodes to loop over, the db connection is going to be opened and closed 10 times (well, connection pooling will probably prevent that, but still...)

You are also loading the entire 'posts' table into a dataset for seemingly no reason.  You're not changing any of the values in the dataset yet you are calling an update on it repeatedly (at "save teh shanges").  If the 'posts' table is even remotely large, this is going to suck a lot of memory for no reason (on a handheld device, no less).

Comment: i fixed that look ath the query again .. :)

Comment: You want to insert a record only if the hash does not exist already, right?  If so, you don't even need to iterate over a datareader.  Instead, just do "select count(*) as hashcount from posts where hash=@endhash" ; if the value is zero, then insert the record.

Comment: @Aviatrix:  You are still adding *new* parameters to the parameters collection of the command object each time through the loop instead of re-using the ones already there.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you closing the Database Connection **inside** the while loop?
The code you posted **should** throw an exception when you try to call **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()** with an unopen DB connection object.

[SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.executenonquery(VS.80).aspx) method returns the number of rows affected.
Why don't you check whether it is returning 1 or not in the debugger as shown below?

```
int rowsAffectedCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is anything returned from "Select * FROM posts Where hash=@endhash"?

If not, nothing inside the while loop matters....

Answer (score 1):

You've got some issues with not implementing "using" blocks. I've added some to your inner code below. The blocks for the connection and select command are more wishful thinking on my part. I hope you're doing the same with the data adapter.

```
using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var nodeItem = rssDoc.SelectNodes("/edno23/posts/post");

    foreach (XmlNode xn in nodeItem)
    {
        using (
            var selectCommand =
                new SqlCeCommand(
                    "Select * FROM posts Where hash=@endhash",
                    connection))
        {
            var msgText = xn["message"].InnerText;
            var c = xn["user_from"].InnerText;
            var avatar = xn["user_from_avatar"].InnerText;
            var endhash = GetMd5Sum(msgText);
            selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@endhash", endhash);
            selectCommand.CommandText =
                "Select * FROM posts Where hash=@endhash";
            using (var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var msgs = reader["hash"].ToString();

                    if (msgs == endhash && msgs != null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    const string COMMAND_TEXT =
                        "INSERT INTO posts([user],msg,avatar,[date],hash) VALUES(@username,@messige,@userpic,@thedate,@hash)";
                    using (
                        var insertCommand =
                            new SqlCeCommand(
                                COMMAND_TEXT, connection))
                    {
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", c);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(
                            "@messige", msgText);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(
                            "@userpic", avatar);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@thedate", dt);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add(
                            "@hash", endhash);
                        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            // executes query
                    }
                    adapter.Update(data); // saves teh changes
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Of course with the additional nesting, parts should be broken out as separate methods.

Comment: Thanks for working out solution but i think was using the wrong sql command all along ;) instead of ExecuteReader() that reads everything i needed ExecuteScalar() that returns only 1 result and i don't need more :) i just need to make sure the the hash is/isnt there :) http://avi.pastebin.com/f5aca84f4 << Sometimes its more simple than it looks like :D

Answer (score 0):

How to debug programs: http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/debug.php

Seriously, can you post some more information about where it's working?  Does it work if you use SQL Server Express instead of SQL CE?  If so, can you break out SQL Profiler and take a look at the SQL commands being executed?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that you're trying to reuse the same SqlCeCommand instances.

Try making a new SqlCeCommand within the while loop.  Also, you can use the `using` statement to close your data objects.

---

Why are you calling `adapter.Update(data)` since you're not changing the DataSet at all?  I suspect you want to call `adapter.Fill(data)`.  The `Update` method will save any changes in the DataSet to the database.